# Interpretation of Coefficients of Expanded Cyclotomic Polynomials

Tags: number-theory, cyclotomic-polynomials, mobius-function

Working out the following definition of the [Cyclotomic Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial)
$$    {\displaystyle \Phi _{n}(x)=\prod _{\stackrel {1\leq k\leq n}{\gcd(k,n)=1}}\left(x-e^{2i\pi {\frac {k}{n}}}\right),}
$$
you'll get
$$
{\displaystyle x^{\varphi(n)}-x^{\varphi(n)-1}\sum _{\stackrel {1\leq k\leq n}{\gcd(k,\,n)=1}}e^{2\pi i{\frac {k}{n}}}} + \dots + 1
$$

You'll spot right away that the next to leading coefficient gives the [Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function):
$$    {\displaystyle \mu (n)=\sum _{\stackrel {1\leq k\leq n}{\gcd(k,\,n)=1}}e^{2\pi i{\frac {k}{n}}}}
$$

For the final $1$, you'll get:
$$
\prod _{\stackrel {1\leq k\leq n}{\gcd(k,n)=1}}\left(-e^{2i\pi {\frac {k}{n}}}\right)=\left(e^{\frac{2i\pi}{n} \sum_{\stackrel {1\leq k\leq n}{\gcd(k,n)=1}}k}\right )\prod _{\stackrel {1\leq k\leq n}{\gcd(k,n)=1}}(-1)=\left(e^{\frac{2i\pi}{n}\frac{n}{2}\varphi(n) }\right )(-1)^{\varphi(n)}=+1,
$$
which is expected since the coefficients are symmetric and $x^{\varphi(n)}$ also has $+1$.

> Do the other terms also have number theoretical interpretation?

UPDATE:

A first partial result found at OEIS: [Coefficient of $x^2$ in the $n$-th cyclotomic polynomial.](https://oeis.org/A086823)

*If $n$ is odd, $a(n) = 1/2 (\mu(n)^2-\mu(n))$,*
*if $n$ is even, $a(n) = 1/2 (\mu(n)^2-\mu(n)) - \mu(n/2)$, where $\mu$ is Möbius function...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Chris pointed out in his answer, the coefficient of the $m$th term of a cyclotomic polynomial is the [elementary symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_identities#Expressing_elementary_symmetric_polynomials_in_terms_of_power_sums) $e_m$ in the primitive $n$-th roots of unity, $\zeta_1,\zeta_2,...,\zeta_{\varphi(n)}$.

And $e_m$ can be written in the following way:

$${\displaystyle {
\begin{aligned}
e_{m}&={\frac {(-1)^{m}}{m!}}B_{m}(-p_{1},-1!p_{2},-2!p_{3},\ldots ,-(m-1)!p_{m})\\
     &=(-1)^{m}\sum _{r_{1}+2r_{2}+\cdots +mr_{n}=m \atop r_{1}\geq 0,\ldots ,r_{m}\geq 0}\prod _{i=1}^{m}{\frac {(-p_{i})^{r_{i}}}{r_{i}!i^{r_{i}}}}\\
\end{aligned}}}
$$

where the $B_n$ is the complete [exponential Bell polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_polynomials#Exponential_Bell_polynomials).

Now $p_k(\zeta_1,\zeta_2,...\zeta_{\varphi(n)}) $ can be seen as the [Ramanujan sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan%27s_sum) evaluated at $k$:
$$
p_k(\zeta_1,\zeta_2,...\zeta_{\varphi(n)}) =\sum _{\stackrel {1\leq t\leq n}{\gcd(t,\,n)=1}}e^{2\pi i{\frac {t}{n}k}}=c_n(k)
$$

So 
$$
{\displaystyle e_{m}={\frac {(-1)^{m}}{m!}}B_{m}(-c_n(1),-1!c_n(2),-2!c_n(3),\ldots ,-(m-1)!c_n(m))}
$$

and *e.g.* $$e_2=(-1)^2\left( \frac{(-c_1)^2}{2!1^2} + \frac{(-c_2)^1}{1!2^1} \right) = \frac12 \left( c_1^2-c_2 \right) \\ \color{grey}{\; \; \overset{?}{=} \frac12 \Big(\mu(n)^2-\underbrace{(\mu(n)+2(1-\bmod(n,2))\mu(n/2))}_{\overset{?}{=}c_2}\Big) }$$

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you mean by "number theoretical interpretation", but the coefficients will, up to sign, be the [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial#Definition) in the primitive $n$-th roots of unity.

For $n$ prime, these coefficients are all $1$.

For $n=2p$, where $p$ is an odd prime,  they alternate between $1$ and $-1$.  See [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial).

Comment: No not really, rather what other arithmetic functions are composed as elementary symmetric functions. Thanks anyway...

Comment: ... hmmm, but after thinking twice, it seems that this is the right way. I'm struglling to get my own answer in accordance with your general approach: Let $\mu(n)$ be the elementary symmetric polynomial $e_1(=p_1)$. Due to Newton's Identities $e_2=\frac12(e_1p_1-p_2)$, which is close to the odd case, but doesn't work out in general. Can you help? Is this a special property of the Möbius function..?